# How to best visualize time interval difference and compute a single measure

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, data-transformation, data-mining, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a table like as shown below

```
subject_id   lab_test_id    lab_test_date       value    difference

"10005606"  "20364112"  "2143-12-06 02:32:00"   "1.3"   "13:10:00"
"10005606"  "20364112"  "2143-12-06 15:42:00"   "1.3"   "02:02:00"
"10005606"  "20364112"  "2143-12-06 17:44:00"   "1.3"   "10:11:00"
"10005606"  "20364112"  "2143-12-07 03:55:00"   "1.3"      NULL
"10005866"  "20364112"  "2149-10-01 19:30:00"   "2.1"   "07:42:00"
"10005866"  "20364112"  "2149-10-02 03:12:00"   "2.2"   "08:51:00"
"10005866"  "20364112"  "2149-10-02 12:03:00"   "2.1"   "04:59:00"
"10005866"  "20364112"  "2149-10-02 17:02:00"   "1.6"     NULL
```

the difference column indicates the time difference between each of the lab tests

Now, the doctor likes to know how often these measurements are done for each patient?

How can I best convey this information? Should I capture the average difference between lab tests?

For example, for patient = 10005606, it is 8 hours. Meaning adding all different values and divide by total number of records. 25 hours, 30 mins (approx)/3 records = 8 hours approx

Is there any other better way to represent this using median or any other measure etc?

Can guide me with this?

Comment: If the sequential differences are sufficiently normal for your tastes, you could use the mean & SD, if not, you could use a standard nonparametric summary (min, 25th%, 50th%, 75th%, max). Is that all you're after? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica - I am looking for a way to represent the frequency of a specific lab test for each patient. For ex: I want to convey to the doctor that, lab test named "ABC" is captured on average every 12 hours for each patient. Similarly, another lab test named "DEF" is captured every 4 hours for each patient..

Comment: So, for each lab test, I would like to know how often it was captured for each patient and then let the doctor know that it is done on average every `X hours` for each patient..

Comment: Of coure, any other suggestions that you may have is also welcome